# Atme ICE basic connection

Tags: c

I got Atmel ICE basic, 6pin wire and atmega 1248, how I should connect the pins.
I tried to look from data sheet, but I cant sent the code in atmega.

http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42330-Atmel-ICE_UserGuide.pdf

http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8...ega164A_PA-324A_PA-644A_PA-1284_P_summary.pdf

So my wire connection is:
[image]

```
MISO  pin 7,
MOSI  pin 6,
SCK   pin 8,
GND   pin 11,
RESET pin 9,
Vcc   pin 10
```

I still get this error:
[image: STILL coming this....]

Comment: Please edit your original post to add more information.

Comment: JTAG-ICE is not the same as the good old ISCP/ISP programming header, which uses the microcontroller's SPI interface to program the flash.

Comment: This question was [cross-posted to *Robotics*](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/6609).

Answer (score 1):

The connections are described in the "Memory programming" section, "Serial downloading" subsection, "Serial Programming Pin Mapping" subsubsection.

[image: Serial pin mapping]